# I get 0 in all values when I use getBondingClientRect

Tags: javascript, getboundingclientrect

I trying to know the information about a div a element cuz I'm just learining about this function but I get 0 in all the values or sometimes I get this error **cannot read properties of null (reading 'getboundingclientrect')**

```
 <style> 
    .box{
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background:#009879 ;
        margin-top: 500px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="title">Element.getBondingClinetRect - JS DOM - dcode</h2>
   <div class="box"></div> 


   <script>
    const box = document.querySelector("div.box");
    
    const rect = box.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
    console.log(rect);

   </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Top of that should be 0. Since it's top is on the 0th pixel from the top. As for the error you got, it's because box is null (presumably your selector isn't correct). Look at getBoundingClientRect on mozzile docs. for the info you need.

Comment: As @DrunkWolf suggested, it seems like your code can't find the element you selected in your DOM. Are you sure you are executing your JavaScript after the DOM has finished rendering?